# Find vector properties after canvas rotation

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

EDIT: I did a video to explain what I wan't to do https://youtu.be/-6I503Urhvg

**Objective**: Find initial X,initial Y,final X and final Y points on canvas after rotation.

**Problem**: Formula is not working in my code and I need to find out what am I doing wrong.

**Question:** I would like to know if the formula I am using is right and how to use it properly to find **objective**.

Formula I am using is:

> nX = x * Math.cos(-angle) - y * Math.sin(-angle)
>
> nY = x * sin(-angle) + y * Math.cos(-angle)

The Formula seems to almost  work as it closely follows the rotation of the vector. I am using little squares to see what is the position that the formula is giving me.

Formula in code:

```
this.nix = this.ix * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) - this.iy * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
        this.niy = this.ix * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) + this.iy * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
        this.nfx = this.fx * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) - this.fy * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
        this.nfy = this.fx * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) + this.fy * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
        ctx.fillRect(this.nix,this.niy,5,5);
        ctx.fillRect(this.nfx,this.nfy,5,5);
```

```js
/*GLOBAL*/var check,lineSquare,rotation,lineRotate;
rotation = 0;
check = false;
lineRotate = false;
function lineRotateBtn(){
    lineRotate = true;
}
function setRotate(){
    var intervalo2 = setInterval(function(){rotation += 0.01;},1000/60);
}
function load() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('box');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function player(x, y, width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;

        this.vx = 3;
        this.vy = 3;

        this.up = false;
        this.down = false;
        this.left = false;
        this.right = false;

        this.drawn = function () {
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
            if (this.up) {
                this.y -= this.vy;
            }
            if (this.down) {
                this.y += this.vy;
            }
            if (this.left) {
                this.x -= this.vx;
            }
            if (this.right) {
                this.x += this.vx;
            }
        }
    }

    var players = new player(100, 100, 20);

    var keyUp, keyDown, keyLeft, keyRight;
    keyUp = 87;
    keyDown = 83;
    keyLeft = 65;
    keyRight = 68;
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyDown, false);
    function checkKeyDown(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == keyUp) {
            players.up = true;
        } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown) {
            players.down = true;
        } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft) {
            players.left = true;
        } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight) {
            players.right = true;
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp, false);
    function checkKeyUp(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == keyUp) {
            players.up = false;
        } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown) {
            players.down = false;
        } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft) {
            players.left = false;
        } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight) {
            players.right = false;
        }
    }

    document.onmousemove = mouseMove;
    function mouseMove(event) {
        event = event || canvas.event
        mouseX = event.pageX;
        mouseY = event.pageY;
        mouseX = mouseX - 11;
        mouseY = mouseY - 13;
        document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = mouseX + " " + mouseY;
    }

    function line(ix, iy, fx, fy) {
        this.ix = ix;
        this.iy = iy;
        this.fx = fx;
        this.fy = fy;

        this.update = function () {
            this.nix = this.ix * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) - this.iy * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
            this.niy = this.ix * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) + this.iy * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
            this.nfx = this.fx * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) - this.fy * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
            this.nfy = this.fx * Math.sin(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180))) + this.fy * Math.cos(-(rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
            ctx.fillRect(this.nix,this.niy,5,5);
            ctx.fillRect(this.nfx,this.nfy,5,5);

            var v1 = {}; //Player
            v1.vx = players.vx;
            v1.vy = players.vy;
            v1.m = Math.sqrt(v1.vx * v1.vx + v1.vy * v1.vy);
            v1.dx = v1.vx / v1.m;
            v1.dy = v1.vy / v1.m;
            var v2 = {ln: {}}; //Line;
            v2.ix = this.ix;
            v2.iy = this.iy;
            v2.fx = this.fx;
            v2.fy = this.fy;
            v2.vx = v2.fx - v2.ix;
            v2.vy = v2.fy - v2.iy;
            v2.m = Math.sqrt(v2.vx * v2.vx + v2.vy * v2.vy);v2.dx = v2.vx / v2.m;
            v2.dy = v2.vy / v2.m;
            v2.ln.vx = v2.vy;
            v2.ln.vy = -v2.vx;v2.ln.dx = v2.ln.vx / v2.m || 0;
            v2.ln.dy = v2.ln.vy / v2.m || 0;
            var v3 = {};
            v3.vx = v2.ix - players.x;v3.vy = v2.iy - players.y;
            var dp1 = v3.vx * v2.dx + v3.vy * v2.dy;
            var dp2 = v3.vx * v2.ln.dx + v3.vy * v2.ln.dy;

            if (dp1 > -v2.m && dp1 < 0) {
                if (dp2 <= 2 && dp2 >= 0) {
                    console.log('colision');
                    if (players.up && players.right){
                        players.x -= players.vx*2;
                        players.y += players.vy*2;
                    }
                    players.x -= players.vx;
                    players.y += players.vy;
                }
                if (dp2 < -1 && dp2 >= -4) {
                    console.log('colision');
                    if (players.down && players.left){
                        players.x -= players.vx*2;
                        players.y += players.vy*2;
                    }
                    players.x += players.vx;
                    players.y -= players.vy;
                }
            }
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(this.ix + v2.vx / 2, this.iy + v2.vy / 2);
            ctx.rotate(rotation * (Math.PI / 180));
            ctx.translate(-(this.ix + v2.vx / 2), -(this.iy + v2.vy / 2));

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(this.ix, this.iy);
            ctx.lineTo(this.fx, this.fy);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.restore();

            document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "dotProduct1: " + dp1 + "v2.m: " + (-v2.m) + "<br>" + dp2;
        }
    }
    var linez = new line(300,300,400,400);

    var intervalo = setInterval(animation, 1000 / 60);
    function animation() {
        check = true;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        players.drawn();
        linez.update();
    }
}
```

```css
#box {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#button {
 border: none;
 background-color: gray;
 width: 70;
 height: 50;
}
canvas {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
html {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 font-family: courier new;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="load()">
  <canvas id="box" width="1330" height="500"></canvas>
  <button onclick="setRotate()">Rotate</button>
  <h2 id="test1"></h2>
  <h2 id="test2"></h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The formula you have given is only valid for vectors that are rotating around the origin. Unless this is what you want (rotating around the origin), you must translate the vectors to the origin, apply the formula, and then apply them back to their original location. Also, make sure your angles are in radians and not degrees.

Comment: He does have degrees to radian conversion, but for efficiency and code robustness he should convert `rotation` to radians just once.

Comment: @JimPedid Could you make a step by step answer? I am having trouble to understand this stuff.

Comment: First be clear on what you're asking: are you trying to rotate the object around the origin? (This is like you turning, where everything rotates around you.) Or are you trying to rotate an object in its place? (This is like a top spinning in front of you.) It sounds like you're rotating the entire canvas, and then you want to know the vectors' positions after the rotation. Is this correct?

Comment: The rotation type is the one shown when you click the rotate button, it rotates around itself, like a wheel. The thing I need to know is the position of it's starting point and end point after it rotates. I translate and rotate the canvas than I undo it, so only the object I want rotates. The problem is that his position doesn't rotate with it I need to get his real position relative to normal(before rotation) canvas. In the bottom of the page there is the mouse position, if you put the mouse over the vector and get vectors position you will see it's not the same. I can illustrate if you need.

Comment: @JimPedid The answer is above. There was no space to mention you.

Comment: It is not clear yet what you want. Try to formulate a problem better.

Comment: It's more common to use a [transformation matrix](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/) to track coordinates in transformed versus original space. Here is [JS matrix tool](https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js)  by Stackoverflow's K3N.

Comment: @markE I am trying to avoid the transformation matrix for now.

Comment: @Timeºº Fair enough. If you just want to learn the raw math, take a look at the internal math of the transformation matrix tool and you will find exactly what you're looking for. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to video, your rotation is about left top window corner - coordinate origin.

To make rotation about **arbitrary point cx, cy**, you have to use these formulas:

```
 NX = CX + (X0-CX) * Cos(Theta) - (Y0-CY) * Sin(Theta)
 NY = CY + (X0-CX) * Sin(Theta) + (Y0-CY) * Cos(Theta)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of those variables?

Comment: x0,y0 - coordinates before rotation, nx,ny- after rotation, theta - rotation angle

Comment: CX, CY = Canvas X, canvas Y?

Comment: I have written `rotation about arbitrary point cx, cy`- this is center of rotation

Comment: Great, it works, thank you. Does that formula apply to other shapes? Like squares.

Comment: That formula could be applied to any point rotated about some center. Square vertices too.

Answer (score 0):

The first key concept here is that you need to recognize where the origin of rotation is occurring. When you rotate a canvas, it is being rotated around and axis that is perpendicular to the page; in two-dimensional parlance, it is being rotated around an origin point.

Consider the vectors whose tail is the origin and whose tip is at some point (X, Y), where X and Y are measured from the origin (in their appropriate unit.). We can calculate the new rotation point (X', Y') using the formula that you have mentioned above:

```
X' = X cos(A) - Y sin(A) and 
Y' = X sin(A) + Y cos(A), where A is the angle of rotation measured in radians.
```

We can recover X and Y from X' and Y' by doing a rotation of -A as well:

```
X = X' cos(-A) - Y' sin(-A)
Y = X' sin(-A) + Y' cos(-A)
```

This is the formula you have in your post, and it's correct.

What if I have a vector that doesn't have a tail that starts at the origin? Well, it turns out that you simply have to apply the transformation to the tail of that vector to get the new tail, and then again to the head to get the new head. If you have a vector that starts at (A, B) and ends at (C, D), then the transformed vector will be (A', B') and the head will be (C', D'). You can use the inverse to go back to (A, B); (C, D) from the rotated frame.

If you are using this formula and not getting the right answer, then make sure you are correctly measuring from the origin that is being rotated around. Chances are that you are calculating the original vector correctly, but you're missing a few key offsets that are really what you're trying to measure.

Comment: I did a video to clarify the question.